# Notepad++ how to find a string and then modify second string on the same line

Tags: notepad++

I have something like this

```
ROSE is 08-07-23 PURPLE
JASMINE is 12-07-23 PINK
SKY is 12-08-23 BLACK
```

How to find ROSE and then replace PURPLE with RED. Sameway if there is JASMINE then change PINK to white. Only the colors need to be changed based on the first string and all others must remain the same.

Comment: What should be the result for `ROSE is 08-07-23 PINK` or `JASMINE is 12-07-23 PURPLE`?

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++ on the Replace dialog first you need to click the Regular Expression radio button to select Regular Expression.  Then you need to search for `^(ROSE.*)PURPLE` and replace it with `\1RED`  The way that works is:

In the search:

- `^` This is the beginning of the line
- `(...)` is the capture group that maps to `\1`
- `ROSE` is the word you are looking for
- `.*` is all the rest of the text until `PURPLE`
- `PURPLE` is the text that you will replace with `RED`

In the replacement:

- `\1` is all the stuff that was captured with `(...)`
- `RED` is the text that replaces `PURPLE`

Comment: Not sure if it is wanted or not but this replaces `ROSE is 08-07-23 PINK` with `ROSE is 08-07-23 RED`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to  modify `ROSE is 08-07-23 PINK` or `JASMINE is 12-07-23 PURPLE`, use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:(ROSE)|(JASMINE)).+\K((PURPLE)|(PINK))`
- Replace with: `(?1(?4RED:$3))(?2(?5WHITE:$3))`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    (?:             # non capture ggroup
        (ROSE)          # group 1, "ROSE"
      |               # OR
        (JASMINE)       # group 2, "JASMINE"
    )               # end group
    .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
    \K              # forget all we have seen until this position
    (               # group 3
        (PURPLE)        # group 4, "PURPLE"
      |               # OR
        (PINK)          # group 5, "PINK"
    )               # end group 3
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists (i.e. ROSE is found)
    (?4         # if group 4 exists 'i.e. PURPLE is found)
        RED         # then put RED
    :           # else
        $3          # put the value
    )           # endif
)           # endif
(?2(?5WHITE:$3)) # Same explanation as above
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]