# Notepad++ how to find a string and then modify second string on the same line - multiple same strings

Tags: notepad++

> hello="ROSE" is 08-07-23 color="PURPLE"
> hello="JASMINE" is 12-07-23 color="PURPLE"
> hello="SKY" is 12-08-23 color="PURPLE"

How to find ROSE and then replace PURPLE with RED. Same way if there is JASMINE then change PURPLE to white. Only the colors need to be changed based on the first string and all others must remain the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ how to find a string and then modify second string on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76856155/notepad-how-to-find-a-string-and-then-modify-second-string-on-the-same-line)

Comment: Why do you ask twice the same question? I've given you a valid answer!

Comment: @Toto This is a subtly different question, the input text has more characters. But I agree: why has the asker written two questions and not edited the earlier one. (I had not noticed the earlier question until a few minutes ago.)

Answer (score 0):

Do a RegEx replace of `((hello="ROSE" is [\d-]+ color=")PURPLE")|((hello="JASMINE" is [\d-]+ color=")PURPLE")` with `(?1$2RED")(?3$2white")`.

Explanation:

This does a search for either of the phrases to be modified (I have assumed that the numeric part can be any value). The replacement keeps the front part of the matching text and adds the required new colour.

```
(                                        Group 1, first alternative
  (hello="ROSE" is [\d-]+ color=")       Group 2, text that is needed in the result
  PURPLE"                                Itself
)                                        End of group 1
|                                      OR
(                                        Group 3, second alternative
  (hello="JASMINE" is [\d-]+ color=")    Group 4, text that is needed in the result
  PURPLE"                                Itself
)                                        End of group 3
```

The replacement

```
(?1                                      If group 1 matched, then
  $2RED"                                   Insert group 2 and 'RED"'
)                                        Else (when not matched) insert nothing)
(?3                                      If group 3 matched, then
  $2white"                                 Insert group 4 and 'white"'
)                                        Else, nothing
```

Comment: Thank you! This search and replace did work for me